# How to extract a value from a variadic template parameter pack by index?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, compile-time-constant

I want to write a function `magic_get`, which can extract a value from a parameter pack by index, for example:

```
int n = 0;
n = magic_get<0>(1, 3, 5, 7);
assert(1 == n);
n = magic_get<1>(1, 3, 5, 7);
assert(3 == n);
n = magic_get<2>(1, 3, 5, 7);
assert(5 == n);
n = magic_get<3>(1, 3, 5, 7);
assert(7 == n);
```

How to implement `magic_get`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
template <size_t N, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) magic_get(Args&&... as) noexcept {
    return std::get<N>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(as)...));
}
```

Change `decltype(auto)` to `auto` and add a trailing return type of `decltype(/* the whole returned expression here */)` if C++14 features are unavailable.

---

Tupleless version:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename Tfirst, typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<N == 0, int>...>
decltype(auto) magic_get(Tfirst&& first, Args&&... as) noexcept {
    return std::forward<Tfirst>(first);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Tfirst, typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<N != 0, int>...>
decltype(auto) magic_get(Tfirst&& first, Args&&... as) noexcept {
    return magic_get<N - 1>(std::forward<Args>(as)...);
}
```

Note that this does not work in clang, thanks to [clang bug 11723](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11723). Replacing `std::enable_if_t<N != 0, int>...` with `std::enable_if_t<N != 0, int> = 0` is a simple workaround.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid constructing a tuple object?

Comment: @xmllmx Yes, it's possible, but why reinvent the wheel? The optimizer will optimize everything out since the tuple is a tuple of references and so its destructor is trivial.